# About a SQL Query (HAVING and COUNT)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, rdbms

I'm learning a database course on Coursera and met a question. Thanks so much if anyone can help me out.

In a table as below, the question is:

> 'List the average number of resources used (NumberFld) by plan number.
>   Only include location number L100. Eliminate plans with less than two
>   event lines containing location number L100'.

My answer is:

```
SELECT PlanNo, AVG(NumberFld) AS AvgNumResources  
FROM EventPlanLine  
WHERE LocNo = 'L100'   
GROUP BY PlanNo                   
HAVING COUNT(LineNo) > 1;
```

While the sample answer is:

```
SELECT PlanNo, AVG(NumberFld) AS AvgNumResources,    
COUNT(star) AS NumEventLines  
FROM EventPlanLine   
WHERE LocNo = 'L100'   
GROUP BY PlanNo  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I think I have kind of figured out what does the sample answer mean, but I would like to know if my answer is feasible.

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the other. `Count(*)` and `Count(LineNo)` should yield the same result here assuming that `LineNo` has no NULL values which could reduce the count in your query.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply! Yes, there's no NULL values in LineNo column. Each PlanNo has its own 'LineNo 1,2,3....'. So my answer is even more 'optimized', right?

Comment: No, your answer is no more optimized than the sample answer.  Also, your answer is less clear because a reader needs to know/wonder whether `LineNo` can be null.

Comment: Why does it matter if there is null value in LineNo? Wouldn't that be seen as 'not greater than 1' and therefore be filtered? Excuse my ametaur question